# how to ignore first loop and continue from second in foreach?

Tags: php

I use foreach loop but it always gives an wierd result in the first but others are fine  so i want to remove 1st loop and continue from 2nd...

My code is

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
   echo $a->getAttribute('href');
   echo $img->src . '<br>';
}
}
```

Comment: use a counter and skip the first one

Comment: no problem, i have had to do the same thing many times myself!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){

   if ($counter++ == 0) continue;

   echo $a->getAttribute('href');
   echo $img->src . '<br>';
}
}
```

Comment: This works, although I edited mine as follows:  `if ($counter++ == 0) continue;`

Comment: You can use  `if (++$counter === 1) continue;` instead.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way I can think of in order to skip the first loop is by using a flag

ex:

```
 $b = false;
 foreach( ...) {
    if(!$b) {       //edited for accuracy
       $b = true;
       continue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: thnks 4 taking time to help me bro !

Comment: If I need to skip first 3 rows, then how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            $count++;
            continue;
        }
        echo $a->getAttribute('href');
        echo $img->src . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thnks 4 taking time to help me bro !

Comment: glad to help you. I guess most of us gave you the similar solution within  the same timespan...

Answer (score 1):

```
$nm = 0;
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
  if($nm == 1){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
       echo $a->getAttribute('href');
       echo $img->src . '<br>';
    }
  }
  $nm=1;
}
```

Comment: thnks 4 taking time to help me bro !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna define an extra counter:

```
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){

        if ( $a === reset( $doc->getElementsByTagName('a') ) && $img === reset( $a->getElementsByTagName('img') ) ) continue;

       echo $a->getAttribute('href');
       echo $img->src . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I don't know which will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try array slice in PHP:

```
foreach(array_slice($doc->getElementsByTagName('a'),1) as $a){
   foreach(array_slice($a->getElementsByTagName('img'),1) as $img){
      echo $a->getAttribute('href');
      echo $img->src . '<br>';
   }
}
```