# Exclude the first result from an Array

Tags: php, json

I am currently messing around with iTunes Api and have ran into a problem with the returning process of albums track list returning the first result as the actual album data instead of the tracklist.

```
$loop['artist_name'] = $counted[$x]->artistName;
$loop['album_id'] = $counted[$x]->collectionId;
$loop['album_name'] = $counted[$x]->collectionName;
$loop['track_number'] = $counted[$x]->trackCount;
$loop['artwork_url'] = $counted[$x]->artworkUrl100;
$loop['copyright'] = $counted[$x]->copyright;
$loop['genre'] = $counted[$x]->primaryGenreName;
$loop['release_date'] = $counted[$x]->releaseDate;

$data_b = file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='.$loop['album_id'].'&entity=song');
$response_ab = json_decode($data_b);
print '<pre>';
print_r($response_ab);
print '</pre>';
```

The above portion for `print_r` returns the following data.

```
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [wrapperType] => collection
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [wrapperType] => track
            )
```

Then continues onward down the track list, how can I remove the first `[0]` option from my loop? It appears this only returns the album name anyway when I am trying to get the tracklist.

Comment: `results` is not a stdClass instance, but a mere _array_ (an array that _contains_ stdClass objects) … and once you realize that, researching how to remove the first element from an array should be easy enough, if still unknown.

Comment: [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-shift.php), yo

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25437158/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10465344/2943403 and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to skip elements in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387193/how-to-skip-elements-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test the below code however it should work.

```
$data_b = file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='.$loop['album_id'].'&entity=song');
$response_ab = json_decode($data_b);

$count = $response_ab->results;
$arr = count($count);
for($a = 1; $a < $arr; $a++) {

// do some cool stuff here

}
```

Comment: Have you just "done all of the work" for the OP after complaining about it?  (I don't support your variable naming choices.)  Please explain your code-only solution.  Every posted answer should endeavor to educate thousands of future researchers.